# My local.xml file doesn't have a session tag defined. Is it normal?

Tags: magento-1.9, session, local.xml

I was wondering changing the way Magento deal with sessions and for my surprise I discovered my `/app/etc/local.xml` doesn't have a `session_save` tag set.

Is it seems to be a problem? Is it safe to set it up manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem to set it manually. If the tag is not set `files` is default value.

See `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract`

```
/**
 * Retrieve session save method
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSessionSaveMethod()
{
    if (Mage::isInstalled() && $sessionSave = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_NODE_SESSION_SAVE)) {
        return $sessionSave;
    }
    return parent::getSessionSaveMethod();
}
```

And parrent one ...

```
/**
 * Retrieve session save method
 * Default files
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSessionSaveMethod()
{
    return 'files';
}
```